# how to find whether the element exists in TBXML?

Tags: iphone, tbxml

In my `XML`,i need to find the element tag whether it exists or not using `TBXML`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819506/tbxml-parsing-using-objective-c

Comment: i just tried with value of attribute name where as nil or not..after getting crash,i realized that i need only the particular element is exist or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enter code hereYou will check if element is non nill than it exists.. as

```
TBXMLElement *rootElement = [xml rootXMLElement];

TBXMLElement *yourTag = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"YourTagName" parentElement:rootElement];
if(yourTag)
   NSLog(@"This element exists");
else
   NSLog(@"This element does not exist");
```